# Learn more about how .NET works

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks

I just had a quick phone interview. The interviewer asked me a few questions like:

- How does C# work?
- What is the CLR and what does it do?
- What is C# code converted to?

Other than the CLR question (for which I gave a very vague answer), I didn't know the answers. There were a few others related to .NET that I don't remember, but I didn't know the answers to those either.

I'll admit that my knowledge is more high-level, but I feel like I have a basic grasp of how .NET works. Either way, I got a second interview, but he said I "need to brush up on how .NET works" before my next interview.

So...I'm not exactly sure how to do that...any advice?

I guess I should also mention that I've been out of college for 2 years, and I've been working professionally since then building ASP.NET web applications. Before that, I had no .NET experience.

Comment: If you have two professional years working on actual projects and your employer is indecisive because you can't regurgitate THEORY, he's obviously an idiot.

Comment: It's an interview question.  How else do you (quickly) filter out the chaff?  I do not agree that "two professional years working on actual proejcts" is an automatic qualifier for a job.

Comment: I would take experience over theory any day.

Comment: @Kirk: Of course not, but automatically blowing off a professional because he can't remember what version of the CLR exports to a particular file under what subfolder is dumb. Now, if the dev can't say what the .NET does...well, that's like a C++ programmer not knowing what a header file is.

Comment: Unfortunately, I frequently get hung up on theory. I had an interviewer for another job ask me "How long does it take to sort an array? How much longer does it take to sort an array of 1000 items than an array of 100 items?" It was more of a computer science question than anything, but I didn't know the answer.

Comment: @Steven: For help answering that question - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @Anton, I don't agree . A good mix of the two is needed and not one over the other. DEGREE Plus EXPERIENCE = good I.T Professional. Experience on its own means V.lucky Bast* !!!

Comment: @Steven post the array question seperately ... I am interested in seeing what the top dogs on here come up with. I already have an answer and i am eager to find out.

Comment: CAREFUL guys!!!! you are having a logical discussion.... ooooops there I said it 'discussion' run, run away from the mod police, they'll lock the topic just because you both have different opinons.... ooooo might get argumentative, we don't want that! /sarcasam.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This article on Wikipedia can give you a good idea about these 3 questions: [.NET Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)

[image]

Comment: +1 for taking the time to post a diagram as opposed to the typical answers.

Answer (score 10):

I recommend [CLR via C#](http://tinyurl.com/3alejm9), which is a great book that shows *exactly* how C# code works "under the hood."

Comment: I second this recommendation.  You don't have to understand what's happening in the guts of the CLR to be a good developer, but it's interesting stuff and can come in handy if you start working with trickier stuff and want to know why things are behaving the way they do.  My guess is that the interviewer was trying to gauge the OP's level of self-directed interest, and (given the follow-up advice for the next interview), to gauge how well he can quickly learn something new.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: @Jeroen, a classic article. :)  The truth of the matter is that we're all working at some level of abstraction and we only dig deeper if we're interested or if we're forced to in order to diagnose some particularly thorny issue.  There are endless levels and not enough time to understand them all.  Nowadays, of course, if there's a tricky problem outside the scope of your understanding, you can always post the question on SO and somebody is bound to have traveled the necessary dark tunnels to have found the answer.  As long as you know enough to describe the problem.

Comment: In my opinion you can never know enough about the technology you're using. So i *always* want to dig deeper.

Answer (score 7):

Taking the questions one at a time...

### How does C# work?

I would ask the interviewer what exactly he means by this—does he want features of C# such as [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx), or [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)?  Does he want to know how people develop for C#?  Does he want a comparison to C/C++?  This is a vague question with many possible answers.

### What is the CLR and what does it do?

The [Common Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) is the virtual machine responsible for execution of .NET byte code (in CIL).  It is the .NET equivalent of Java's JVM.

### What is C# code converted to?

C# is compiled into the [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), formerly known as MSIL.  It is a type of byte code.  To be able to see it and translate it back into .NET languages, you can use a tool like the [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to view the CIL code as well as how it would look in C#, VB.NET, etc.

Comment: @Aristos I disagree, if the question is vague, ask for more information.

Answer (score 2):

my favourite metaphor/simile is its like having a car, you don't need to know how the engine actually works (water pump, cylinders, spark plugs)... in order to drive a car, but if you did know the extra details it would help your drive even better and be able to actually understand/diagnose some problems you may encounter with the car...

You don't need to know much about the CLR to code an asp.net web site, but if you were to get into the guts of the CLR you might alter the way you code some things to make it even faster to run.

Answer (score -1):

MSDN has reference material on these subjects, e.g.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5tkafs1(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score -1):

those should be easy questions if you have realy been working with .net for 2 years,

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/mcts.aspx

**Edit:** throwing in my comments bellow, certainly not well known guidelines of any kind... just for discussion

Comment: The tests have the best of intentions, but without any experience to back up the knowledge, they are virtually useless. It's like reading how to ride a bike. Until you try to ride a bike, reading how to ride a bike really has no value. Well, unless you are tested on the knowledge on how to ride a bike.

Comment: I disagree, the certs are API tests, experience is whatever your boss needs to get done, which in big part is specific to his app and won't be usefull in the next interview.

Comment: i dont agree with you @GenEric.... unless you are theory person who just read to teach than working on a real world project.

Comment: @Nisar, the goal is to make the most of the API, in this case the .Net framework and use it as it's intended. Otherwise, and this is from my experience, real world projets often end up written by lamers who are lost in the framework, making all sorts of contraptions to replace what is already existing(membership, globalization, logging, caching, unit testing, deployement best practices). The case where real world experience is relevant is if you work in a very common field(e-business) and knowledge is all reused from one job to the other, otherwise knowing the api allows you to adapt faster.